# How to Create database table when Plugin installed/activated, and delete database when Plugin deleted

Tags: plugin-development, database, oop

I am trying to create new WordPress plugin with object oriented programming.I want to create database when plugin activation and delete database when plugin deleting.Below is my code its not working for me.I have two files one is main plugin file other one is plugin functions included files.

main file code as below:

```
<?php
/* 
Plugin Name: Test Reviews1
Plugin URI: https://test.in/
Description: This Test Plugin. 
Version: 1.0 
Author: Test 
Author URI: https://test.in/ 
License: GPLv2 or later 

    */
    new test_plugin();
    class test_plugin{

        public function __construct(){

            $this->plugin_dir = plugins_url( '' , __FILE__ );
            include('inc/inc.php');
            $this->security = new hidemysite_security();



        }

    }
```

include file code as below:

```
<?php
class hidemysite_security{

 public function __construct() {
  if (is_admin()) {
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'activate'));
      register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_remove_database' );

  }
}

public function activate() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'md_things';
  $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        text text NOT NULL,
        url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}   

public function my_plugin_remove_database() {
     global $wpdb;
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'md_things';
     $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name";
     $wpdb->query($sql);
     //delete_option("jal_db_version");
} 
//    
}
```

Could You Please Help Me ?

Comment: What in this code is not working?

Comment: Database not creating when activating the Plugin.And also database not deleting at the time of plugin deletion.

Comment: What error are you getting? Enable debuging in your wp-config.php file by changing define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ) to define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ) and see error message. It will help you finding the actual issue.

Comment: Did you try wppb.io (plugin boilerplate) because it includes all useful actions. Ie. action when activate or deactivate. Btw you can use uninstall.php for catching uninstall action. Simple just put dele_option or smt.

Comment: Related: [Create a table in custom plugin on the activating it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220935/create-a-table-in-custom-plugin-on-the-activating-it/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead-

```
class hidemysite_security{

    public function __construct() {
        if (is_admin()) {
            register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array( $this, 'activate'));
            register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'my_plugin_remove_database' ) );

        }
    }

    public function activate() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'md_things';
        $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        text text NOT NULL,
        url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }   

    public function my_plugin_remove_database() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'md_things';
        $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name";
        $wpdb->query($sql);
    //delete_option("jal_db_version");
    } 
//    
}
```

These 2 lines were modified-

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array( $this, 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'my_plugin_remove_database' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to register the activation and deactivation hook outside the class definition.

```
/*
 * Fired during plugin activation.
 **/
 class My_plugin_activator() {
    public static activate() {
     // write your db code here
    }
 }
```

.

```
/*
 * Fired during plugin deactivation.
 **/
 class My_plugin_deactivator() {
    public static deactivate() {
     // write your code here
    }
 }
```

Now in your plugin's main file

```
function activate_my_plugin() {
   My_plugin_activator::activate();
}

function deactivate_my_plugin() {
   My_plugin_deactivator::deactivate();
}
```

Now register your function to the activation/deactivation hook.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_my_plugin' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_my_plugin' );
```

Answer (score 0):

though i was just trying to create table and the table was not created because i was not selecting the database name in query .after adding the name ,it worked perfectly
the code is following :

```
  $query="CREATE TABLE `jobs`.`$dbp_tb_name` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL ,
     `pass` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
     `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
     `phn` INT NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE = InnoDB;" . $wpdb->get_charset_collate() . ";";
```